# redirection to profile page as soon as registration is successful

Tags: javascript, angularjs, token, angularjs-ng-route

Not getting **redirected** to login page my profile page is an html and main is the login page. I tried redirecting it to both the pages but it keeps going to the catch block as soon as a relocation is provided.

```
angular.module('meanhotel').controller('RegisterController', RegisterController);

function RegisterController($http) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.register = function() {
    var user = {
      firstname: vm.firstname,
      lastname: vm.lastname,
      email: vm.email,
      password: vm.password
    };

    if (!vm.email || !vm.password) {
      vm.error = 'Please add email and password.';
    } else {
      if (vm.password !== vm.passwordRepeat) {
        vm.error = 'Please make sure the passwords match.';
      } else {
        $http.post('/api/users/register', user).then(function(result) {
          console.log(result);
        //  vm.message = 'Successful registration, please login!';
          vm.error = '';
        // $window.location.href('/main');
        //$location.path('#!/profile');
        $window.location.href = '/main.html';

        }).catch(function(error) {
          vm.error = "User already exists";
          console.log(error);
        });
      }
    }
  }
};
```

app.js:
routing in app.js is as follows. Profile is a simple html page with a logout button. not sure if the user is getting passed to it as well. I am setting the user in another controller.

```
angular.module('meanhotel', ['ngRoute', 'angular-jwt']).config(config).run(run);

function config($httpProvider, $routeProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthInterceptor');

  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'angular-app/main/main.html',
      access: {
        restricted: false
      }
    })
    .when('/register', {
      templateUrl: 'angular-app/register/register.html',
      controller: RegisterController,
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      access: {
        restricted: false
      }
    })
  .when('/profile', {
      templateUrl: 'angular-app/profile/profile.html',
      controller: LoginController,
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      access: {
        restricted: true
      }
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
}

appModule.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix("");
}]);

function run($rootScope, $location, $window, AuthFactory) {
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, nextRoute, currentRoute) {
    if (nextRoute.access !== undefined && nextRoute.access.restricted && !$window.sessionStorage.token && !AuthFactory.isLoggedIn) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $location.path('/');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: can you also show your `config`?

Comment: i think $window is not injected and is giving error, so it is going to catch block. Try using only window instead of $window or inject $window in the controller

Comment: Which version of angularJS you are using? is is (<1.4, 1.5 or 1.6)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try once using

```
$location.path('/profile');
```